# For refresh flow, do I need to create an OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor for my client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

I'm using the refresh flow sample, but i added the instrospection middleware since my resource server is separated from my authorization server.  Using the angular app, I'm able to connect to the authorization server.  Everything works. But I noticed in the Implicit Flow sample that the following code was added:

```
            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("aurelia", cancellationToken) == null)
            {
                var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "aurelia",
                    DisplayName = "Aurelia client application",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { new Uri("http://localhost:9000/signout-oidc") },
                    RedirectUris = { new Uri("http://localhost:9000/signin-oidc") }
                };

                await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor, cancellationToken);
            }
```

Do I need to add something similar to this for the Refresh flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't configure OpenIddict to require a `client_id` for token requests (by calling `options.RequireClientIdentification()`) then creating an application in the database is not mandatory to be able to use the refresh token flow.